# Reordenar posição em uma sequencia via MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

Tenho uma tabela de `Chamados`. Tenho que adicionar uma coluna inteira que vai se chamar `sequencia` e que vai ser usada para fazer buscas na ordem que o usuário quiser.

Só para ilustrar: o chamado vai ter umas flechas, quando clicar na flecha que aponta para cima, esse chamado vai aumentar o número da coluna `sequencia`, e alterar todos os outros registros para que aquele chamado fique acima do que estava acima. Mesma coisa se clicar na flecha para baixo, alterando sua ordem, lembrando que a coluna sequencia não pode ter números repetidos.

Alguém pode ajudar? Estou desenvolvendo em `JAVA` e `MySQL`.

EDIT:

Baseado nos comentários, decidi fazer assim:

```
UPDATE chamado SET sequencia = sequencia + 1 WHERE cod = 1
UPDATE chamado SET sequencia = sequencia - 1 WHERE cod = 2
```

Assim ele aumenta o valor da sequencia onde o usuário clicou, no caso o código 1, e diminui o valor do código acima acima para que o código 1 tenha um valor mais auto que o código 2, para fazer ao contrario:

```
UPDATE chamado SET sequencia = sequencia - 1 WHERE cod = 1
UPDATE chamado SET sequencia = sequencia + 1 WHERE cod = 2
```

Comment: Não tem nada pronto, ou é tarefa de casa?

Comment: Tenho tudo pronto, pediram para adicionar essa funcionalidade no Software, e estou me batendo como posso fazer isso.

Comment: @AronKS sua pergunta está bem ampla. Entendi o que tem que ser feito, mas exatamente, qual é a sua dificuldade, ou o problema?

Comment: Especifique melhor, de preferência o que você já tentou. Pedir uma solução do 'zero' não demonstra nenhum esforço da sua parte em resolver o problema..

Comment: @Aron, tá usando algum framework?

Comment: Pensei em pegar o registro, e incrementar + 1 nele, e um FOR nos outros registros, para incrementar os de cima, e diminuir os de baixo, mas nosso banco de dados não é muito rapido (é externo), não teria uma maneira mais facil de resolver?

Comment: @GustavoCinque Não, somente usando o NetBeans.

Comment: Aron, não tenho muita experiencia em `swing`, mas a ideia seria, a cada vez que um registro fosse qualificado com "+1", a tabela se recarregaria, e nas funções que modelam a tabela, haveria uma separação pelo campo `voto` (por exemplo). Também não sei se é a melhor das ideias...
Tem o modelo de `Chamado` implementado? Se sim, seria só criar um novo campo dentro dele.

Comment: Desculpe, tinha entendido "criar outra tabela" em vez de "coluna" lá em cima. Aconselho utilizar o framework `Hibernate` para poder mapear os models mais tranquilamente, e sem ficar queimando a cabeça com `SQLs`, mas acredito que o projeto já esteja muito avançado para fazer isso.

Comment: [nota ao editor] @Earendul, confira o guia [Como devemos formatar perguntas e respostas?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1084/201), especialmente a parte sobre o uso das `\`\``.

Comment: AronKS, clique em [edit] e atualize a pergunta, confira [ask] para mais detalhes. Desse jeito: 1) Os votos negativos podem ser revertidos. 2) Você vai receber respostas em vez de cometários pedindo esclarecimentos.

Comment: Esta pergunta parece ser descontextualizada porque é sobre um problema especifico que não ajudará mais ninguém. Além disso a pergunta é muito ampla e tem a resposta na própria pergunta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Além da sua solução para inverter a posição de dois ítens, que é esta:

```
UPDATE chamado SET sequencia = sequencia + 1 WHERE cod = 1
UPDATE chamado SET sequencia = sequencia - 1 WHERE cod = 2
```

Voce pode ter uma assim para mudar o ítem arbitrariamente para qq posição:

Guarde numa variável o `cod` e `sequencia` do chamado original para subir posições:

```
UPDATE chamado SET sequencia = sequencia + 1 WHERE sequencia >= destino AND sequencia <= original
UPDATE chamado SET sequencia = destino WHERE cod = codigosendomexido
```

E para descer posições:

```
UPDATE chamado SET sequencia = sequencia - 1 WHERE sequencia <= destino AND sequencia >= original
UPDATE chamado SET sequencia = destino WHERE cod = codigosendomexido
```