# Fazer um "Update" com soma de um número que está como caractere

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, soma

Preciso realizar um `update` com soma em uma tabela cuja coluna é do tipo `text`. Exemplo:

```
UPDATE produto SET codigo = 'codigo'+ 1;
```

Tenho o seguinte retorno:

```
UPDATE produto SET codigo = 'codigo'+ 1;
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "codigo"
LINHA 1: UPDATE produto SET codigo = 'codigo'+ 1;
```

Se estiver errado por favor me indiquem o método correto.

Comment: da forma como descreveu você está concatenando a string _codigo_ com 1.. teria então _'codigo1'_ salvo no banco.. é isso que quer?

Comment: não amigo, na verdade preciso somar o valor ja existente entende, tipo tenho o código 361 e quero que ele acrescente +1. e que repita isso pra todos os codigos..

Comment: acho que não está muito claro, mas pode estar relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/31633/69359 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/296101/69359

Comment: @ErenilsonAlencastro Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Resolvido, fiz da seguinte forma:
CREATE TEMPORARY SEQUENCE codigoproduto START WITCH 361;

DEPOIS:

UPDATE produto set codigo= nextval('codigoproduto');

Comment: É legal você vir e compartilhar o resultado. O único problema no caso atual é que a resposta, apesar de ter resolvido no seu cenário específico, não produz exatamente o que foi pedido na pergunta (e se produziu no seu caso, é quase uma coincidência).

Answer (score 2):

É bem simples, transforme a coluna em tipo numérico.

Use texto para colunas descritivas, mesmo que tenha só dígitos numéricos nela. E use colunas numéricas quando precisa fazer contas, como esta.

É até possível fazer desta forma, mas é tão mais complicado que o ideal é mudar a coluna. Não trabalhe com conceitos errados que o problema vai ficando cada vez maior.

Se insistir precisará antes de mais nada converter a coluna para numérico, fazer a conta somando 1 e depois convertendo novamente para texto.

```
UPDATE produto SET codigo = to_char(to_number(codigo, '999999') + 1);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Update/Padding.sql).

Mas isso pode variar de acordo com sua necessidade.

Entenda a diferença entre o que é o dado, o que é a coluna, a sintaxe, o que faz cada coisa no código. Sem entender o que cada coisa faz no seu código não conseguirá programar. E esta é a parte fácil da programação. Não tem ideia da parte difícil. E como é fácil fazer tudo errado e funcionar e achar que está conseguindo algum resultado, quando está causando enormes problemas.

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno, Porém no meu caso nao deu certo:
 UPDATE produto SET codigo = to_char(to_number(codigo, '361') + 1);
ERROR:  function to_char(numeric) does not exist
LINHA 1: UPDATE produto SET codigo = to_char(to_number(codigo, '361')...
                                     ^
DICA:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
  UPDATE produto SET codigo = produto.codigo + 1;
```

mas lembre-se que você estará adicionando + 1 para todos os seus códigos pois você não está passando nenhuma condição para o UPDATE.

Comment: Bom dia obrigado pelo retorno, porém tenho o seguinte erro :
UPDATE produto SET codigo = produto.codigo + 1;
ERROR:  operator does not exist: text + integer
LINHA 1: UPDATE produto SET codigo = produto.codigo + 1;

Comment: @ErenilsonAlencastro pode postar a estrutura da tabela?